# DB2 stored procedure in sql using squirrel. Unable to loop

Tags: sql, loops, stored-procedures, db2, squirrel-sql

I am unable to use %notfound as I get the following error.  How can I get past this?? I'm unable to figure out a way to use cursors apart from this method. Please help with other methods to use a cursor loop without using %notfound.

> The character "%" following "EXIT WHEN c_rqstid" is not valid.. SQLCODE=-7, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=3.63.123 SQL Code: -7, SQL State: 42601

I have set @ as the delimeter and the code is as follows

```
create PROCEDURE TEST111()
AS: 
begin 
DECLARE c_id integer; 
DECLARE c_isactive integer; 
DECLARE c_status integer; 
CURSOR c_rqstid is SELECT REQUESTID,REQUESTSTATUS,ISACTIVE FROM SAMPLE.REQUEST;
 OPEN c_rqstid;
  FOR LOOP FETCH c_rqstid into c_id,c_status,c_isactive ;
  ----will code this later
  EXIT WHEN c_rqstid%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
 CLOSE c_rqstid;
end
@
```

Thanks for any help in advance...

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Good question, well formatted.  Good luck!

Comment: What type of OS is your DB2 server running on: IBM i (fka OS/400), LUW (Linux, Unix, Windows), or z/OS? And what version?

Comment: @WarrenT Its on Windows and 10.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to check the SQLCODE or SQLSTATE variables:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0009028.html

```
 DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';

 WHILE(SQLSTATE = '00000') DO
    SET p_sum = p_sum + p_sal;
    FETCH FROM c INTO p_sal; 
 END WHILE;
```

Comment: It appears Sherri is trying to use PL/SQL compatibility, eh?

Comment: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000751.html shows an example of using %NOTFOUND.

Comment: @Charles  I tried that but the SQLSTATE doesn't change and I end up in an infinite loop. Am I missing something???

Comment: @WarrenT Thanks but the examples mentioned are for in-string usage of '%'. I need to use a function named %NOTFOUND.

Comment: @Charles Hey that worked. The SQLSTATE resets on every statement so you have to check it immediately after the fetch. I had placed it wrong initially but read up the link you posted and got my mistake. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Ah, I'm not familiar with the PL/SQL compatibility stuff..  from the web page http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053869.html the format is SQL%NOTFOUND

Comment: @Charles No luck there too.. I guess squirrel doesn't understand those functions.